# How to use column number(s) instead of name(s) to conditionally subset rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use `pd.notnull` to subset rows in a pandas DataFrame where `value` is not missing. However, instead of using the column name I want to use the column number. How can I do this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'value': [2, 6, np.nan, 8, np.nan]
})

# This works
df[pd.notnull(df['value'])]

# This doesn't work
df[pd.notnull(df.columns[1])]
```

Comment: You probably meant: `df[pd.notnull(df[df.columns[1]])]` though the `iloc` solution is probably better.

Comment: Bear in mind that depending on which Python version you're using, the order of the dictionary may not be in the order you think it is... so it's plausible your dataframe might have index as column 1 and value as column 0 here...

Comment: Try doing `print({'index': [], 'value': [], 'cabbage': [], 'avacdo': []})` in your interpreter and see what order you get as a test :)

Comment: @pault `{'index': [...], 'value': [...]}` is the dictionary that's constructed which `pd.DataFrame` then uses... the order it sees the keys in that dictionary isn't necessarily (unless in Python 3.6+) the order they're written...

Comment: @pault in 2.7 for instance, if you were to swap the lines so `value` came before `index`... your DataFrame would still have col 0 as index and col1 as value as that's just the way the keys get iterated over...

Comment: @JonClements I see what you mean. I take back my previous comment, misunderstood. Using `index` as a column name/dict key led to some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate columns by index, use `iloc`

```
df[pd.notnull(df.iloc[:, 1])]
```

Or

```
df[pd.notnull(df[df.columns[1]])]
```

`columns[1]` returns `'value'`, and `pd.notnull('value')` makes no sense. You either have to use this return value to get your column's `pd.Series` by using `df['value']` *or* use the index directly to get the column using `iloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to `dropna` with `subset`

```
df.dropna(subset=[df.columns[1]])
Out[407]: 
   index  value
0      1    2.0
1      2    6.0
3      4    8.0
```